# Selecting what table column to "count" from when tables are related (joined)?

Tags: excel, powerpivot

I have a table of Accidents, and a table of Vehicles. Their relationship is one to many; i.e.- an accident can have multiple vehicles involved, but one vehicle cannot be a part of many accidents. They're joined/ related by a "Report Number" column.

I've created a Pivot table with “Weather” from the Accidents table into COLUMNS, “DRIVER AGE GROUP” into ROWS, and “REPORT NUMBER” from Vehicles table to VALUES.

I'm having trouble understanding why Report Number is chosen from the vehicles, instead of accidents table to form a count of involved vehicles. I understand the numbers change if I use the Report Number from accidents, but am unable to explain myself why they change.

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to correct me here; We select a count of the report number from vehicles because we want to know how many vehicles have been involved across all accidents; not how many accidents have vehicles been a part of. Selecting a count of report number from accidents would net us how many accidents has a vehicle been a part of.